# how to filter by a range of time on a specified date in HiveQL

Tags: database, date, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to write a query that will return all data entries on the current date between two arbitrary hard coded hours (i.e.: 07:00:00.000 - 09:00:00.000)

This is my current query:

```
SELECT http_message.request.method as http_verb, http_message.request.headers["host"][0] as domain, regexp_replace(http_message.request.headers["Referer"][0], concat("https://", http_message.request.headers["host"][0], "/"), "") as path, http_message.response.headers["x-page-id"][0] as routing_key, agent_info.user_agent as user_agent, event_header.published_timestamp as request_timestamp
FROM prod_runtime_and_orchestration.edge_secure_access_log_event_v1
WHERE acq_date = '2022-07-07'
AND http_message.response.status=200 
AND http_message.request.method = "GET" 
AND (http_message.response.headers["x-page-id"][0] in ("page.Infosite.Information", "Homepage", "page.Search") 
     OR http_message.response.headers["x-page-id"][0] RLIKE "")
LIMIT 100
```

I'm trying to figure out how to hard code set the variable acq_date to return me data on [date] between the hours of [start hour] and [end hour].

Thank you in advance